# Rules Of Inference (Simplification)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Hi is it possible I can use Simplification Rule on two negated terms

E.g.

C1: ~q and ~p

C2: ~q Simplification Rule, C1

[Simplification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBfKd.png)

Comment: Welcome to maths SE. Could add some details on your problem? I could be your thought on the problem, or the background of the problem.

Comment: Hi thanks for you help i'm referring to the picture which I posted

Comment: YES; the rules holds more generally for formulas : $(A \land B) \to A$. In your case, formula $A$ is $\lnot q$ and formula $B$ is $\lnot p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use it on two negated terms, Simplification also called [conjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination), which states:

$$\frac{P\land Q}{\therefore P},\frac{P\land Q}{\therefore Q}$$

Where $P,Q$ could be any formulas, for example:

$$\frac{(\neg P)\land (\neg Q)}{\therefore \neg P}$$

We even have:

$$\frac{\neg P\land (\neg Q\land R)}{\therefore (\neg Q\land R)},\frac{(\neg P\land \neg R)\land \neg Q}{\therefore (\neg P\land \neg R)}\text{ etc.}$$

All of those examples are using conjunction elimination.

Comment: Thank You So Much